Botón no muestra el color que yo asigno
estoy haciendo una practica en android studio, y mi problema es el siguiente
En pantalla me muestra el botón con el color naranja, pero en el archivo dentro de la carpeta drawable yo tengo que el color sea de color gris.
Asi es el código xml del activity:
<Button
        android:id="@+id/close_session"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/close_session"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_close_session" />

Y este es el del archivo donde especifico la forma y el color que quiero:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/hint_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>

Ya intente aplicando el color desde el activity con backgroundTint y tambien desde los estilos, pero me sigue apareciendo como en la imagen.

Ya probaste limpiando y reconstruyendo el proyecto?, a veces Android Studio tiene problemas con la actualización de recursos (caché)

Si ya lo hice, y siguió lo mismo

Verifica que @color/hint_gray esté definido correctamente. Asegurate que no exista otro recurso con el mismo nombre 'btn_close_session'. Prueba en otro emulador o dispositivo.
